# how to query a sub object of an object with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, object, methods

I have a Customer object. The Customer object may contain multiple Address objects.

I would like to set up a method on the Customer object to `GetCity` for example.

Now, each Address object has an addressId so I'm trying to query the property via linq.

Below is my code (i've cut it down for this issue)

the Customer object...

```
public class Customer
{
    private string _customerNo;
    private List<CustomerAddress> _addresses = new List<CustomerAddress>();
    //other members immitted from this sample


    //constructor code, immitted from this sample

    public List<CustomerAddress> Addresses
    {
        get { return _addresses; }
    }
    //other properties immitted from this sample    

    public string GetCity(string id)
    {
        var city = (from a in _addresses
                        where a.AddressID == id
                        select a.City).Single();

        return city;
    }   
}

the Address Object...
public class CustomerAddress
{
    private string _addressid;
    private string _city;
    //other members immitted from this sample

    public CustomerAddress(string strAddressID, string strAddressLister, string strAddress1, string strAddress2, string strAddress3, string strCity, string strState, string strPostCode, string strCountry,
        bool booDefaultAddress, string strDeliveryAddress, string strInvoiceAddress, string strPayAddress, string strVisitAddress, string strDeliveryTerms, string strShipVia, string strRouteId)
    {
        _addressid = strAddressID;
        _addresslister = strAddressLister;
        _address1 = strAddress1;
        _address2 = strAddress2;
        _address3 = strAddress3;
        _city = strCity;
        _state = strState;
        _postcode = strPostCode;
        _country = strCountry;
        _defaultaddress = booDefaultAddress;
        _deliveryaddress = strDeliveryAddress;
        _invoiceaddress = strInvoiceAddress;
        _payaddress = strPayAddress;
        _visitaddress = strVisitAddress;
        _deliveryterms = strDeliveryTerms;
        _shipvia = strShipVia;
        _routeid = strRouteId;
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    //CustomerAddress Properties
    ////////////////////////////
    public string AddressID
    {
        get { return _addressid; }
    }    
    public string City
    {
        get { return _city; }
    }
    //other properties immitted from this sample
}
```

When I run the `GetCity(id)` method on the Customer object I get the error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

I also tried the following code in the linq query but got the same results.

```
public string GetCity(string id)
{
    var city = (from a in this.Addresses
                    where a.AddressID == id
                    select a.City).Single();

    return city;
}
```

and...

```
public string GetCity(string id)
    {
        var city = (from a in this._addresses
                        where a.AddressID == id
                        select a.City).Single();

        return city;
    }
```

I know that the Customer object does contain Address objects within it, but i'm not sure how to get the `GetCity` Method to work.

Any help would be appreciated. If i've missed any important info please let me know.

Comment: can you post a Customer object, with adresses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is either that the _addresses collection does not contain any elements at all, **or** that the _addresses collection does not contain any elements with the `AddressID` equal to id (probably more likely).

How `Single()` work is that it throws an exception if there is either fewer than 1 (0) or more than one item that match your given criteria. If you simply want to return `null` when there are no matches use `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: I think everyone has a point here... but this answer triggered a thought.... I think the id I was passing into the method had white space after it, to I used a Trim() method on the string and now I am getting a value.
Every Customer object has at least one Address object on it, so the address is never empty, this is way it confused me so much... The id was originating from a sql source with a specific field length, so this needed trimming :) 

Thanks for the responses :)

Answer (score 3):

```
where a.AddressID == id
```

Is filtering out all your addresses, so you get that error message when you call `Single` on an empty enumeration.

You can switch `Single` to `SingleOrDefault`, but I think the main issue is with the address comparison

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the linq query is not returning any items where do you populate the List? are you sure that the requested id exists?

Single needs a IEnumerable with exactly 1 item  in it